# Java Play 2 - Function as a parameter in scala

Tags: java, templates, scala, playframework-2.0

I have problems to write reusable code in scala.

If i have something like

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Guides.addComment(category,title)) {
```

Is there a way to replace it with a variable?

pseudo code

```
@(func : Function)
@helper.form(action = func) {
```

Edit:

Oh.... now it's kinda obvious. The function itself should return a string , so I guess i can just say something like this

```
@(func :String)
..
```

.

```
return ok (form.render(routes.Guides.test()))
```

Testing it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest an alternative? Use [Call](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/mvc/Call.java) directly.

```
@(route: Call)

@helper.form(action = route) {
  ...
}
```

In Scala, you could even pass only a part of the route and fill the rest from the controller (very useful when you're using pagination).

Comment: Can you explain this a little how to use this for pagination?

Comment: Can you ask it in a separate question please?

Answer (score 2):

figured it out.

with

```
routes.Guides.test().url
```

you get the url and then you can use it as a parameter

for example

```
@guidesComment((routes.Guides.addComment(ug.category,ug.title)).url)
```

guidesComment looks like this

```
@(func: String)
```

Then use it like this

```
<form action="@func" method="POST">
```